# How to connect mesh vertex groups with bones?

Tags: animation, mesh, vertex-groups, blend-modes

I can't understand, how to connect mesh vertex groups to bones and I'm beginner in blender. In first step I've created a new one file ([download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Fl0c3AhVDZMFBDNXI4TmV5eGc/view?usp=sharing)) with Cylinder and added two connected bones. After that, I've added Armature object as Modifier to the Cylinder mesh.
[image]

After that I've created vertex group named g1 in Cylinder mesh.

[image]

And painted in Weight mode:
[image]

But I can't understand, how to assign connect this 'g1' vertex group to the bone named 'Bone.001'. After that manipulations, when I'am trying to rotate bone 'Bone.001' in Pose Mode, no mesh deformation applied.
[image]
How can I "glue" end of the 'Bone.001' to the 'g1' vertex group?

Thank you.

Comment: give them the same name

Comment: I'am sorry... them - for whom? Same name for 2 bones, or same name for second bone and for vertex group?

Comment: the vertex group should have the same name of the bone

Comment: Chebhou, can you post your comment as Answer?

Comment: will do , just a minute : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the **Armature modifier** with ***Vertex Groups*** enabled :

[image]

the vertex groups should have the same names as the bones so they can be bound together

[image]

Comment: @ArtUrlWWW you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need an armature modifier, set to vertex groups. Vertex groups that have the same name as the bone are affected by it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxz7LQ-xKjM

there is a video on such matters vertex groups and so starts around the 8 minute mark.